# Take the sum of zero and a date/time-like string, how to interpret the result (which is a number)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement like need to add the two cells like A1 and A2 as like below format similar to Excel sheet.
A1 cell value "0"
A2 cell value 43:45 (Text format)
A3 cell value "=A1+A2"
And the expected result would be 1.822916667 in Excel result. I would like to know what process/functionality behind this cell values.
Can anyone please let me know the actual process behind adding the two cell values?

Comment: You should you use a more precise title, since you are trying to add a fraction to a number. I'm not an Excel expert, but I'd say both cells need to be formatted as numbers to sum up the values. More precisely `A2` need to be formatted as Fraction: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-numbers-as-fractions-0121ecac-1773-4f2d-8cd3-7db51fd83b77 and you would need to change to `43/45`

Answer (score 1):

`43:45` is interpreted as date/time when you add 0 to it.

It is equivalent to 1 day, 19 hours and 45 minutes, or the date/time `1/1/1900  7:45:00 PM`

Expressed as a number, that would be `1 + 19.75/24 = 1.822916667`